# Worklight 6.2 - Issues with logging

Tags: eclipse, logging, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I've seen a couple of issues with Worklight 6.2 studio around logging.

1. If you change the logging config, an extra  line gets added to the server.xml at eclipse startup.
2. The dev server doesn't seem to pay attention to the log size limit.

To repro #1

- Change your logging configuration.  We set our log level to INFO and upped the size to 400.  This results in the following line in the server.xml file:

`<logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" copySystemStreams="false" maxFileSize="400"/>`

- Shut down and restart eclipse.  As part of the startup process, it adds a 2nd logging line to the end of the server.xml file

`<logging consoleLogLevel="AUDIT" copySystemStreams="false"/>`

Since this line comes later in the file, it takes precedence over the first line for the server.  For the GUI, it displays the contents of the first line.

For #2, it straight up looks like if you change the maxFileSize option on the logging line, the server just doesn't pay attention to it, and still wraps at the default (20, I believe).  I've made sure there aren't 2 logging lines in the server.xml, restarted the server, etc.

If there is any additional info I can provide to help track these down, please let me know.

Comment: Problem #1, as Idan states, is a known issue. For problem #2 (maxFileSize setting not being respected), what log file are you trying to expand the limit for (location/filename)?

Comment: @OrlandoRincón I'm trying to expand the size of the Worklight Development Server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known defect.

If you are an IBM customer or business partner and require a fix for this issue, [you can open a PMR  support ticket](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639) and request a Worklight 6.2 iFix to be produced and delivered to you.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the point 2 it is normal, it is a restriction of Liberty Profile: maxFiles and maxFileSize don't apply to the console.log file.

See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html